# Snowflake - Unsupported Query Type - Using WHERE ... CONNECT BY ... within WHERE EXISTS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try and run the following code, I get the error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated":

```
SELECT '"' || TABLE_CATALOG || '"."' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '"."' || NAME || '"'
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES TBL_LIST
WHERE DELETED_ON IS NULL
    AND GRANTED_ON = 'TABLE'
    AND PRIVILEGE IN ('SELECT','DELETE')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS CHILD, GRANTEE_NAME AS PARENT
                        FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
                        WHERE GRANTED_ON = 'ROLE'
                            AND DELETED_ON IS NULL)
                WHERE GRANTEE_NAME IN (CHILD, CURRENT_ROLE())
                START WITH PARENT = CURRENT_ROLE()
                CONNECT BY PARENT = PRIOR CHILD)
GROUP BY '"' || TABLE_CATALOG || '"."' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '"."' || NAME || '"'
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRIVILEGE) = 2;
```

The goal of this code is to get a list of all tables that my current role has access to the SELECT and DELETE privileges on. I created a minimal example of the problem within Snowflake:

```
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES TBL_LIST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS CHILD, GRANTEE_NAME AS PARENT
                        FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES)
                WHERE GRANTEE_NAME = CHILD
                START WITH PARENT = CURRENT_ROLE()
                CONNECT BY PARENT = PRIOR CHILD);
```

I have confirmed that the query evaluates successfully if I remove the nested WHERE or the START WITH ... CONNECT BY sequence.

I want to know why this subquery type is not supported.

Update (6 months later): I came across a similar issue without CONNECT BY being used.

Comment: Hi - how would knowing why this subquery type is not supported by Snowflake benefit you? If you had that knowledge, it's not going to help you write a query that will give you the results you are looking for

Comment: I want to know it because it might be interesting! On a more material note though I only learned the syntax of CONNECT BY yesterday so anything that aids my understanding of how it works could be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Amended your second query to work. Please see if the result is as you expect.

```
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES TBL_LIST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS CHILD, GRANTEE_NAME AS PARENT, GRANTEE_NAME
                        FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES)
                WHERE GRANTEE_NAME = CHILD
                START WITH PARENT = CURRENT_ROLE()
                CONNECT BY PARENT = PRIOR CHILD);
```

Comment: That won't work; the GRANTEE_NAME in the WHERE clause should be aliased (I forgot) as TBL_LIST.GRANTEE_NAME. Your code does not link the subquery table with the FROM table, which is the source of the error.

Comment: ```SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES TBL_LIST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM (SELECT CHILD 
                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS CHILD, GRANTEE_NAME AS PARENT, GRANTEE_NAME
                                FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES)
                        START WITH PARENT = CURRENT_ROLE()
                        CONNECT BY PARENT = PRIOR CHILD
                       UNION
                       SELECT CURRENT_ROLE())
              WHERE GRANTEE_NAME = CHILD);```

Comment: that is how you would re-write it to work. but anyway, I am more interested in why the original query doesn't work